# how to place Post and page content side by side

Tags: loop

Dear Stack Exchange Wordpress community,

I am interested in having two loops on the same page, having the larger one display the Page content and a sidebar display blog posts,and do not know how to go about it. I have searched the archives to still no avail.
Much Appreciation. 
Bill

Comment: Can you please mention if you have tried two loops and the problem you faced with that? Currently the information provided is incomplete so it will be difficult to provide the guidance.

Comment: Easy. **Main block:** `$my_page = get_post( $page_id );`, and **Sidebar block:** `$my_posts = get_posts( $args );`... do whatever you want.

Comment: wow thank you guys so much I really appreciate that so much @ItsMePN I have tried using two loops but both would just show the posts.

Comment: Also from there, I would just pass those into a new query for each loop? @myeenul-islam _

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to use two for loop using two post types.
 **For blog post use below code**

```
<?php query_posts( array(
 'post_type' => array( 'post')
 'showposts' => 5 )
 ); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="post_type">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> "><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <div class="excerpt">
    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**For page post use below code**

```
<?php query_posts( array(
 'post_type' => array( 'page')
 'showposts' => 5 )
 ); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="post_type">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> "><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <div class="excerpt">
    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```